# Adding a ViewGroup to a ViewGroup

Tags: android, viewgroup

I would like to be able to programmatically add a viewgroup to another viewgroup. Both have been defined in xml as follows, along with my onCreate method:

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/firstll"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="first text" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="second text" />
```

secondlayout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/secondll"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="first text" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="second text" />
```

onCreate:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Context context = getBaseContext();

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, null);
    LinearLayout tv = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.secondlayout, null);
    tv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    ll.addView(tv);
    setContentView(ll);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to find a view before you set the content view when you do `findViewById(R.layout.secondlayout)`. Also, `secondlayout` isn't the id of a view, it's the name and id of the layout file.

Try doing

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, null);
LinearLayout tv = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.secondlayout, null);
tv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
ll.addView(tv);
setContentView(ll);
```

Comment: This starts, but I get a blank view, with only the title

Comment: @Frazerm63 odd. Post your `onCreate` method

Comment: I assume the context is:    Context context = getBaseContext();

Comment: No, just use the Activity context. You can replace it with `this`

Comment: Seems to be working now. playing around with the xml layouts seemed to fix it.